# I disabled debug but Google Play Store still tell me that my apk was signed in debug mode

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am having trouble publishing my app in the google store. It tells me that the apk was signed in debug mode yet I have disabled it.
You can see my config in the pictures down below.

Did I miss something ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: is debug enabled in the Android project options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jason answer was the correct one. Thank you.
You need to disable debug in the Android project options.